# How to send list value in Ruby Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a simple form where there is a  list:

```
     <form method ="post" action ="">
     <select>Select subject
        <option value="1">Maths</option>  
        <option value="2">Science</option>
     </select>
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
```

My question is, if I select the option Maths, I would like the value to be sent eg /1. 
What should be written in action? How should the route be written ?

```
       get '' do 


       end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your route could look something like this:

```
post '/subject' do
  @subject = params[:subject]
  # do whatever you want now
end
```

But you would need to give your `select` tag a name and your `form` an action:

```
<form method="post" action="/subject">
    <select name="subject">
    <!-- etc etc -->
```

Also have a look at related questions.

Answer (score 0):

we tend to look at queries as GETs (makes sense, it is after all retrieving information) 
rather than a POST which (doesn't actually change data) yet responds with a result page

a common (gnarly) pattern we often see is to rewrite (in js or redirect) 
to the form

GET '/search/:q1/and/:q2' do
  // result of search filtered by q1 and q2
end

which is also quite neat